# Postgressql Tools/Import greyed out

Tags: postgresql, import

[image]I recently installed PostgresSQL and, previously, in a former install, I was able to import CSV files using Tools/(Import/Export). This is now greyed out, along with Table icon, next to the Query tool icon.

Comment: You are describing the elements of a GUI.  But PostgreSQL is not a GUI system.  There are many GUIs which will work with PostgreSQL, but which one are you trying to use?  Please tag the product name.  And maybe include an image to supplement your description.

Comment: I edited my post such that the PostgreSQL admin tool appears with the greyed Import/Export.  It also shows the GUI with the icon for tables(which also appears greyed out).